# Apply discount Block moving issue in magento2 cart page

Tags: magento2, blocks, shopping-cart

I need to move apply discount block to the summary block in cart page.

I have used below code in 
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" 
destination="checkout.cart.totals.container" before="checkout.cart.totals" />
```

It is not moved to summary block.

Is there anything to achieve like that.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223524/how-can-i-add-coupon-code-on-sidebarorder-summary-in-checkout-page/351813#351813

Answer (score 2):

Try to check this solution. Add layout file with the following name

> checkout_cart_index.xml

into your module and insert xml code like this for moving discount block

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon2" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml"/>
    <move element="checkout.cart.coupon2" destination="cart.summary" after="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and found it working fine.

I think you may have put your code at a wrong place.

Please check it with the following **`checkout_cart_index.xml`** code and let me know if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="checkout.cart.totals.container" before="checkout.cart.totals" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: hi @Mohit, Tried your code, that didn't move the coupon block. it is still same after cache flush also.

Comment: Remove the content of pub/static too.

Comment: Yes, did but no luck, its still in same place.