# Magento2 move coupon code inside summary

Tags: magento2, layout, shopping-cart

I am planing to move the coupon code section inside the summary page,before that i have moved the summary-section under the item list, and moved the cross-sell section next to summary-section.

Now i plan to move the coupon-code section inside the summary section or next to item-list section.

For move inside the summary-section i just used below code

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.summary"/>
```

For move next to order item list section

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="checkout.cart.items" before="checkout.cart.order.actions" after="checkout.cart.form"/> 
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="checkout.cart.container" before="cart-items" />
```

Comment: this can help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223524/how-can-i-add-coupon-code-on-sidebarorder-summary-in-checkout-page/351813#351813

Answer (score 4):

Just add below code in `Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` in your custom theme :-

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.summary" after="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
```

**OR**

If you want to add before checkout button then add below code :-

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.summary" after="checkout.cart.totals.container"/>
```

Comment: Hi dipesh, both the code is not working

Comment: I have tested in default Magento and this is worked for me, make sure with your customization if you have made any.

Comment: Yes, I have moved my summary section next to order-item list, and move the cross-sell section next to summary.

Comment: works as charm...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code this will place coupon code section after estimate shipping section or above cart total container in summary section.

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.summary" after="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Did it work for you @senthil?

Comment: thanks for your support. but it's not working

Comment: are you using any third party theme?

Comment: No, for your kind information, read my post. because i have already moved some elements.